# "will be all present" or "will all be present"

Tags: grammaticality

Which one do we use for this sentence :

Student chairs will all be present for this meeting or "will be all present"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use either:

*Student chairs will all be present for this meeting.*

or

*All student chairs will be present for this meeting.*

The forms:

*Will all be present at the meeting?* or *Will all student chairs be present at the meeting?*

are valid if you are asking a question.

Comment: Those are the two canonical Quantifier-Float sentences; _all_ can float from a position modifying its bound NP (_chairs_) to an adverbial position before a verb. However, _Student chairs will be all present_ is OK in at least one circumstance: if "all present" is a fixed phrase -- e.g, short for "all present and accounted for" -- then this is just a predicate adjective. This assumes, by the way, that _student chairs_ refers to people, not furniture. Except in a very unlikely scenario.